# How to send a telegram message after request on the website?

Tags: python, flask, telegram

I have a Flask app on my server and also a Telegram bot for this website on the other server with common database. I want to send a message in Telegram after certain requests on my website (users make requests and before this they connect Telegram account with website account). What is a proper way to do this? I have no idea at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've stated, you're using a common database between the two servers. Very often, message queues are used for something like this, often using the AMQP protocol. Have a look at something like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), which is a common implementation of this. If you have a setup where the Flask server pushes requests to send messages to the queue, and the Telegram bot reads the queue to check for new messages, you can have easy communication between servers. I'd recommend this approach.

---

Another possibility is to write something like this yourself, using your database as a queue. Write message requests to a table, with each row having a "processed" boolean, which the Telegram bot sets to true after sending the message. There are a couple of downsides to this approach though:

- Many updates and deletes on a database can increase the space usage of the database because of soft deletes;
- If you're going concurrent, you'd need a mechanism to prevent the servers from fetching and processing the same row - AMQP does this for you;
- AMQP can deal with failed requests through a Dead Letter Exchange (DLX). What if Telegram's servers are down or if someone is unreachable, then do you retry the same thing over and over or put it aside for later